# App fabric cache limitation

Tags: caching, appfabric

I am trying to cache long string in the cache. It is limiting itself to 255 char length. I am not able to figure out why?

Is there any way to re configure this?

Comment: sorry, I figured out the answer, We need to set the transport properties in the app fabric configuration. I have another question reg appfabric, posting a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the settings for transportproperties:

```
        transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" maxBufferSize="500000"
```